# IAM Issue with CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, amazon-iam, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I'm having an issue with a seemingly trivial task of getting CodeDeploy to deploy Github code to an AutoScaling Group in a Blue/Green Deployment.

I have a Pipeline setup, a Deployment Group setup, AutoScaling Group, ELB, and LAUCH CONFIGURATION but it fails when it gets to the actual deployment:
[image]

and this my roles in codeDeploy-roles

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "autoscaling:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
            "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions",
            "ec2:DescribePlacementGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLink"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:AWSServiceName": "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
            "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
            "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
            "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
            "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
            "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
            "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup",
            "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
            "autoscaling:EnableMetricsCollection",
            "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
            "autoscaling:DescribePolicies",
            "autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
            "autoscaling:DescribeNotificationConfigurations",
            "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
            "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
            "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
            "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancers",
            "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups",
            "autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
            "autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
            "autoscaling:PutNotificationConfiguration",
            "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
            "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
            "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "tag:GetResources",
            "sns:Publish",
            "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

[image]

Is there a policy that I'm not considering that needs to be attached to this role?

Comment: You need autoscaling group policy in the role! You can use your own or can use the aws managed policy!

Comment: in first policy i use AutoScalingFullAccess

Comment: that is AWS managed policy! Can you paste the policy in the problem ?

Comment: please cek the role in my problem

Comment: What is the trust policy of that role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood,I would rather following steps.

1. You need to create a [CodeDeployServiceRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html) and you just used built in policy.
2. Create a CodeDeploy application and deployment group and assign your CodeDeployServiceRole there.
3. In launch configuration you don't have to worry about CodeDeploy and just config you instance profile with required policies for instance operations.